# What does "y" function for in "voudrais y aller"?

Tags: grammaire

In one of the examples in [French conditional](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/conditional.htm), I found the following sentence:

> Je voudrais y aller avec vous.

But I'm not sure what the `y` functions for. Is it true that if you omit it to just write it as `Je voudrais aller avec vous.`, you can express the same meaning?

I hear that `y` works for a personal pronoun. But I'm not sure then what it stands for in this case...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb *aller* (when describing actual movement) requires somewhere to go to or from and that's where *y* comes in.

> Je voudrais **y** aller avec vous

means *I would like to go **there** with you*.

*Aller* can also be used to form the future tense by meaning *going to* as in *Je **vais** manger tôt* - *I am **going to** eat soon*. In this case there is no movement, so *y* is not used.

*Y* is a pronoun that stands in as a dummy destination when used with *aller*. In English, we can just skip it.

Comment: Thanks. Well then does it *always* have to be used with y if it is used as a *go* verb?

Comment: If you don't specify any other destination (or origin), then yes. _Je voudrais aller au magasin_ - _I would like to go to the shop_. Because I mentioned an actual destination, I don't need to use _y_.

Answer (score 3):

Les deux sens ne sont pas les mêmes, avec ou sans *y* . *y* précise le verbe *aller*.

y aller = aller à cet endroit, dans cette pièce, au cinéma, ...

y est un pronom adverbial, [représente le lieu où l'on est ou le lieu où l'on va.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y)